# Raster Projection

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, arcgis-pro

I am reprojecting an ortho with an unknown coordinate system to the coordinate system matching my feature layers. However, after using the project raster tool in Arcgis Pro, the ortho still projects on a different continent even though it has the correct coordinate system.

The raster data was sent to me as a jpg2. I have tried reprojecting as a jpg2. and as a tif. format. What are some solutions to this problem?

Comment: georeference the image https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/data/imagery/georeferencing-tools.htm example video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3r7ELaxRdDs

Comment: Not clear what you did. You cannot project without knowing original projection.

Comment: If you edit the question and include the raster's extent (before you assigned the desired coordinate system) and state where it's supposed to be, someone can tell you whether it already has any georeferencing and, possibly, what coordinate reference system it's in.